# Parse a nested JSON array with Talend Open Studio and make it a table

Tags: java, arrays, json, csv, talend

I need to parse a Json nested file and extract a csv using Talend Open Studio. The objective is transform the nested Json format into a table.

The Json has the following structure:

It's an array of elements (financial instruments in my specific case) and each element has another array level which represents transactions per instrument.

In the example below we have three elements (represented by fields **Isin** and **Description**) and for each one there could be a set of **transactionDetails.**

```
[{
        "transactionDetails": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "90",
                "nominalAmount": 26000000.0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "95",
                "nominalAmount": 1000000.0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "97",
                "nominalAmount": 30000000.0
            }
        ],
        "Description": "Apple",
        "isin": "ISIN1"
    },
{

        "transactionDetails": [
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "88",
                "nominalAmount": 27000000.0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "99",
                "nominalAmount": 1000000.0
            },
            {
                "tradeDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00",
                "price": "96",
                "nominalAmount": 24000000.0
            }
        ],
        "Description": "Microsoft",
        "isin": "ISIN2"
    },
{
        "Description": "Tesla",
        "isin": "ISIN3"
    }]
```

The ideal output wuld be list every Isin and referenceDate with all the transactionDetails (three per Isin). The table below represents what I mean:

| isin | Description | tradeDate | price | nominalAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISIN1 | Apple | 2023-02-13T00:00:00 | 90 | 26000000.0 |
| ISIN1 | Apple | 2023-02-09T00:00:00 | 95 | 1000000.0 |
| ISIN1 | Apple | 2023-02-13T00:00:00 | 97 | 30000000.0 |
| ISIN2 | Microsoft | 2023-02-13T00:00:00 | 88 | 27000000.0 |
| ISIN2 | Microsoft | 2023-02-13T00:00:00 | 99 | 1000000.0 |
| ISIN2 | Microsoft | 2023-02-13T00:00:00 | 96 | 24000000.0 |
| ISIN3 | Tesla | - | - | - |

**Important : as per the example, not all the instruments have transactionDetails associated with them, but I need to extract them as well into the table (of course with null values in the transactionDetails field).**

I tried in different ways.

1- first one is creating a Json Metadata, I tried the following ways but never getting the desired result, in the screenshots my tentatives:

With **$[*]** absolute path expression

[image]

With **$[].transactionDetails[*]** absolute path expression

[image]

As you can see either the "root values" (Isin, Description) or the transactionDetails are written as an array in the extracted fields instead of being processed as a table per my previous example. Am I making mistakes in setting Absolute or relative path expressions?

2 - Then I tried by using tExtractJsonfields, and I actually succeeded in doing what I wanted but in a very complicated way:

[image]

In this example I'm using different files but with same Json structure.
Here I have two identical tInputJsonFile with "$[*]" as an absolute path expression and with relative path expressions as following
- "isin"
- "Description"
- "transactionDetails[*]"

Then in first tExtractJsonFields I'm extracting Isin, Description and transactionDetails remains as a field with array inside. In the second tExtractJsonFields I'm looping over transactionDetails to extract tradeDate, price and nominalAmount (but this will extract only the records with transactionDetails associated with them, not the others).

So finally in order to join all instruments (the ones with transacionDetails and the ones without) I had to create two tMap (to make the two output dataset having the exact same columns) and then concatenating them with a tUnite component.

Is there a more simple and intuitive way to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You may try another JSON library *Josson* to convert the JSON to csv.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"transactionDetails\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"90\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 26000000.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"95\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 1000000.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"97\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 30000000.0" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]," +
    "        \"Description\": \"Apple\"," +
    "        \"isin\": \"ISIN1\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"transactionDetails\": [" +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"88\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 27000000.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"99\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 1000000.0" +
    "            }," +
    "            {" +
    "                \"tradeDate\": \"2023-02-13T00:00:00\"," +
    "                \"price\": \"96\"," +
    "                \"nominalAmount\": 24000000.0" +
    "            }" +
    "        ]," +
    "        \"Description\": \"Microsoft\"," +
    "        \"isin\": \"ISIN2\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"Description\": \"Tesla\"," +
    "        \"isin\": \"ISIN3\"" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
```

**Transformation**

```
String csv = josson.getString(
    "unwind(+transactionDetails)" +
    ".map(+Description, +isin, +tradeDate, +price, +nominalAmount)@" +
    ".csv()" +
    ".@join('\n')");
System.out.print(csv);
```

**Output**

```
Apple,ISIN1,2023-02-13T00:00:00,90,2.6E7
Apple,ISIN1,2023-02-13T00:00:00,95,1000000.0
Apple,ISIN1,2023-02-13T00:00:00,97,3.0E7
Microsoft,ISIN2,2023-02-13T00:00:00,88,2.7E7
Microsoft,ISIN2,2023-02-13T00:00:00,99,1000000.0
Microsoft,ISIN2,2023-02-13T00:00:00,96,2.4E7
Tesla,ISIN3,,,
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort  but the OP is asking for a Talend solution.